# Hyper-V VM on workstation connected via Check Point VPN

Tags: vpn, hyper-v

I have a windows 10 laptop running a Hyper-V VM. I need the VM to connect to the corporate domain.

Because I'm working from home,  My laptop is connected using Check Point VPN.

If I use the Default Switch., which is set for as internal, I get very slow access to Internet connection from  VM but does not go through the VPN tunnel so I can't contact the domain controller.

If I create a new virtual external switch, connected to my wireless adapter, I get access to Internet connection from VM but does not go through the VPN tunnel so I can't contact the domain controller.

If I create a new virtual external switch, connected to check point virtual adapter, I lose all connectivity to my laptop entirely.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create an external virtual switch. Bind your VM to this switch. Install the VPN client on the VM. Done.

Comment: It's a good idea.  I did this, but then couldn't connect because the VPN client complained that my VM wasn't compliant (because it hadn't been added to the domain yet).  See answer below, I did find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [this microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network), using powershell will help you set this up, although I couldn't follow completely, due to a bit of a lack of expertise I think.

However,  that documentation did lead me to a suggestion that if you install VMWare player (free), as part of its configuration, it creates a number of virtual NICs, one of which is called VMnet8 and is set up for NAT.  There is also some automatic bridging set up.  Once VMPlayer is set up you don't need to use it, just associate the Hyper-V VM's network adaptor to VMnet8 and your VM connectivity will be bridged through the VPN adaptor.